# Firefox is Ignoring Ubuntu hosts File

Tags: server, firefox, proxy, hosts

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and I am using **HTTP proxy** to connect to the INTERNET in my university. I have edited my hosts file as below

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       user-PE62-7RD
10.105.8.13     mail.com www.mail.com
```

but when I type *mail.com* in Firefox it goes to *mail.com* site rather than to IP specified. But when I ping with terminal it is pinging correct IP. And also I can access the Web App on the server using IP address but not the local domain name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using [Manual Proxy configuration], adding the domain "mail.com" or host "www.mail.com" to [No Proxy for] field in your example will solve the problem.
Firefox sends proxy request before resolving the hosts file or dns.

Comment: You should explain more about what [Manual Proxy configuration] is and where it can be found.